# C++ reading off ADC at pace of CLK frequency

Tags: c++, for-loop, indexing, arduino, adc

I am using an hyperspectral sensor from Hamamatsu (C12880MA). So far, I got my firmware done to fit the Atmega328p, timings etc. are working great.

But now, I bumped into some issues regarding reading the measurements off the ADC.

According to my Clock-Signal generation (at variable f between 0.5 and 5 MHz), I need to read off the ADC values at exact "flag" values.
I am using the internal TC1 timer for clock generation. At each toggle of the CLK signal, I set a flag via an ISR to time the other signals / restart the program.

Now to the problem: I know (see datasheet for ref), that the VIDEO Signal of the sensor will appear between the flags "ADC_start" and "ADC_End" at the pace of the generated CLK. I have to read the values through the internal Arduino ADC at exactly the correct flag, to later match with the correct underlaying wavelengths.

Here are the essential snippets of the code:

```
volatile uint16_t flag = 0;
uint16_t data[288]; // define 1d matrix for data storage
  
uint16_t ST_Start = 2; // starter flag for the programm
uint16_t ST_End = 134; // end flag for ST signal
uint16_t ADC_Start = 310; //starter flag for ADC readout
uint16_t ADC_End = 886; //end flag for ADC readout
uint16_t index; //index used for data storage
  
volatile uint16_t End = 1000; // end flag for programm restart and clearing cache
```

The ISR handles increasing the flag on every CPU clock..

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){

if  (flag <= End){

    flag = flag+1;    
} else
{
    flag = 0;
   
    //delayMicroseconds(2000);
}
```

this is my readData function. Unfortunately I have not found the correct way to read the ADC values at the exact flags needed. Say I need to read values at the flags 300, 302, 304, ..., 900 (on every second flag, between an set interval; ADC_Start to ADC_End)

```
void readData() {

    if (flag >= ADC_Start && flag <= ADC_End ){

        for (uint16_t i = ADC_Start; i < ADC_End; i = i+2)
        {
          index  = i - ADC_Start;
          data[index] = analogRead(VID);
        }
                
    } else { }  

}
```

Here´s the data sheet: https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/c12880ma_kacc1226e.pdf
See p.7 for timings.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm living in the past, when things weren't as fast as they are today ... but calling an ISR at (up to) 5MHz seems like a *very* heavy load.

Comment: Isn't the ADC read-off limited to 200k/sec? (But it's been years since I last dug into the datasheets.)

Comment: jumping in and out of an ISR takes 4 clock cycles each. so what makes you think you increase flag each cpu clock cycle?

Comment: @Piglet possibly just lack of knowledge.. any idea on how to sync a change in flag with reading the ADC?

Comment: @Microwave_Woodchuck sync - like the code can't see changes in ISR? Flag must be volatile.
Anyway it looks like you need something faster, for example ARM with DMA...

Comment: @KIIV no this actually works.. it´s about my last code example above. I am trying to find a way to loop through the correct flags at the correct times.. say I want to read my first wavelength at exactly the 302 flag. The next wavelength at the 304 flag, and so on. 

Yeah, I got the Teensy 3.2 here, I think I will port it soon

Comment: @Microwave_Woodchuck ADC in AVR has also auto triggering mode that can be triggered by Timer1 COMPA (or others), if you do it properly, you might be able to completely skip SW part of it. But it requires some digging in datasheet

Comment: BTW, interrupt flags doesn't have to be handled and cleared by interrupt, you can have interrupt disabled and check it in your code (and clear it by writing logic 1 to that bit position - yes, it's cleared by writing log1)

Comment: @KIIV so you´re speaking about the TOV1 register? I thought it only triggers on the actual overflow of TCNT1 not when hitting OCR1A

Comment: There are several flags: OCF1B (compare match B) OCF1A (compare match A) TOV1 (overflow - only if it's wrapping around it's full range). Without interrupt handlers they will be set (if it occurs) and stays set unless you do clear them.

Comment: OCF1A is triggered by the OCR1A value, but it wont work as counter does it? As part of TIFR1 it will be either 1 or 0.. how can I then use this as counter to replace the flag generated in the ISR? Thanks for the help KIIV!